# R: how to compute a power analysis based on a wilcoxon test for paired observations (Wilcoxon signed-rank test)

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test, pairwise.wilcox.test, power-analysis

I want to know if my study and my statistical test is powerful.

I have 16 subjects, all of them took both treatment1 and treatment2. I want to know if the study is powerful by conducting a power analysis to **determine the power of the study**.

**Group 1 : n=16, mean +/ sd => 0.9 +/- 1.4 ;
Group 2 : n=16, mean +/ sd => 1 +/- 0.01**

**The two groups are paired (same subjects)**

I found the package MKpower and function sim.ssize.wilcox.test but I don't quiet understand how to use. I tried this

```
>> rxy <- function(n) rnorm(n, mean = mean(group1),sd = sd(group1))
>> sim.ssize.wilcox.test(rx = rxy,  n.min=8,n.max = 30,step.size = 2, iter = 10000,type="paired")

    n emp.power
8   8    0.3181
10 10    0.4619
12 12    0.5253
14 14    0.6351
16 16    0.6866
18 18    0.7556
20 20    0.8049
```

Am I using this right? and if I follow the result it means the power for n=16 is 0.68, which seems hard to believe ...

**which R function can calculate the power for Wilcoxon signed-rank test, please ?**

Comment: You are calling a function `sim.ssize.wilcox.test` without defining it. Where is this function from? Did you import it from a package?

Comment: I specified "I found the package MKpower and function sim.ssize.wilcox.test" ! ...